# A riley: The Breaking Point

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

My prefix is crossed out, for ancients,

My infix is a valley, for genii,

My suffix is charged, for ever,

And my whole is a breaking point.

What am I, and why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are:

> **TENSION**

*My prefix is crossed out, for ancients,*

> In *ancient* Rome, the number **TEN** is written as an 'X', or *cross*.

*My infix is a valley, for genii,*

> '[Silicon Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Valley)' is a global hub for innovation and new technologies - the playground of innovative *genii*, perhaps. The chemical symbol for the Periodic Table element [silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon) is **Si**.

*My suffix is charged, for ever,*

> As found by @Amoz already, an **ION** is a *charged* particle in chemistry.

*And my whole is a breaking point.*

> Altogether, TEN + Si + ION (with overlap) is **TENSION**: the state of being stretched tight (either physically or mentally) and possibly about to break...

Answer (score 9):

You are an

> EXECUTION!

My prefix is crossed out,

> EX is "ex-ed out"

My infix is a valley,

> A CUT is a synonym for valley

My suffix is charged,

> This is the classic clue for ION

And my whole is a breaking point.

> Together we get EXECUTION, the breaking point, or end, of one's life

Comment: nope. not ex or cut, but ION is correct.

Answer (score 6):

How about a

> decision

This is very much piggybacking on Stiv’s answer but

> deci an abbreviation for ten which is Roman numeral X which is crossed out.

The valley, as identified by Stiv

> si for Silicon Valley

Charged, as identified by Stiv

> ion

And why?

> a decision is loosely synonymous with a breaking point, more so than just tension (sorry Stiv.  I feel like I’m robbing you if this is it.)